# For debugging is there a way to globally configure php5 to output the names of all user-defined functions as it executes them?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a global configuration setting *or* a way to *globally* instruct php5 to print out the names of user-defined functions when any user-defined function executes.

The tricky part is I'd like this to be something I could set in one place, not something that I'd have to manually add to each function.

The goal is to be able to look at a page's output, see an area of concern, enable this mystery mode I'm asking about, refresh the page and instantly see that the area of concern was output by a given php function named "whatever()".

Thanks for any ideas!

(note: I realize this would make a mess of your average php page's output - ie the html would render funny with a bunch of function names suddenly appearing everywhere. That's ok as I would only use this in development/debugging.)

Comment: Not sure about that, but there is [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

Comment: @BradChristie, yeah debug_backtrace is handy, but it requires you to place a call to *it in the function*. But I'm trying to *find* the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/), the standard debugging tool for PHP. You can set a breakpoint and get a regular [stack trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) (which is probably what you're looking for) and even a [function trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) which does, indeed, log all function calls, but it is probably overkill in this scenario.

Comment: Setting a break point requires you to have already identified the function that's outputting the problem content. And the function trace doesn't interleave the function names with the normal output, so without that context it doesn't seem to get me an instant way to see what function was responsible for outputting the problematic html or whatever. I'm probably not explaining this very well :(

Comment: Unless you can override the output methods (`echo` et al) in PHP (I don't think you can) then I think you're not going to find a way to output the name of the function along with the text being output. I suggest you tackle this the old-fashioned way, i.e. with breakpoints.

Comment: I guess I was, in effect, hoping to override whatever php itself uses to invoke user-defined methods (rather than echo). I did something similar for a long-dead cms I developed years ago - it was SO handy to flip a switch and see the function names interleaved with their output - I used that feature every day and miss it greatly.

Comment: Well if you're doing all your output within a certain class, say, you could modify your output methods to check for a flag (say, `$this->debug`) and if it's present output [`__FUNCTION__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (or all of `debug_backtrace()` if you want) along with the output.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to accept your answer. Thanks, belatedly, for the help! Sorry it took so long!